# Problems when merging git branches

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I've been searching and I can't find a scenario like this (I hope I can explain it with clarity).

In my company we use git (with bitbucket) with three branches: "dev", "release" and "master". As a development team we only have access to "dev" and we need to raise a "pull request" to merge with other branches. The path should be:

(local) -> "dev" -> (pull request) -> "release" -> (pull request) -> "master".

But a year ago, someone merged only from "dev" to "release" and "master" got outdated. The rest of the team did some merges from "dev" to "release", so, again, "master" got outdated. But now, when we try to make a merge from "release" to "master", the first thing we notice is that the "pull request" to "master" is including all of the commits existing in "release" and it throws an error telling us that there are conflict and must be fixed manually.

The problem is that we don't have access to "master" and, according to the instructions shown by bitbucket, we need to checkout to "release", make the corrections and merge again to "master", but if I checkout to "release" I don't see the conflicts in the code and can't fix them.

I figure out that the conflicts must be fixed by someone that has access to "master", but I'd like to know if there is a way to make the merges without touching directly "master"? I don't know, maybe by doing a "pull request" but for a past commit (altough I don't see that option)... Or what we can do?

I hope I explained it well and you can help me with this.

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Were there changes to master that do not exist in release?

Comment: @dan1st No, the problem is in a file that was modified in two commits in "Realease" and when trying to make de merge with "Master" this file is causing the conflict

Comment: What merge strategy do you use? (Rebase/3-way-merge or squash)

Comment: "we don't have access to master" do you mean you can't push to master ? or that you don't even have the history of master in your local repo ?

Answer (score 0):

Merge conflicts are symmetrical : if you merge `master` in `release` on your local clone, you will have the exact same conflicts as the ones you see on bitbucket.

So you can :

- merge `master` into `release`
- fix conflicts
- push the result to `release`

after that : opening a PR to merge `release` into `master` won't raise conflicts anymore.